# Vue - @vue/compiler-sfc gives Type Error while building the project

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to upgrade my project from Vue 2 to Vue 3 only i am encoutering a error while building the project.

This is the error that occurs 3 times  :

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')
    at createBlock (C:\Users\POOPKAKA\Documents\Squadra\powerconvert\frontend-vue3\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1988:31)
    at C:\Users\POOPKAKA\Documents\Squadra\powerconvert\frontend-vue3\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1910:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at parse$2 (C:\Users\POOPKAKA\Documents\Squadra\powerconvert\frontend-vue3\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1854:16)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\POOPKAKA\Documents\Squadra\powerconvert\frontend-vue3\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js:64:36)
 @ ./src/main.js 2:0-28 6:10-13
```

This is the code in the App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <AppNavigation></AppNavigation>
    <v-main>
      <v-container class="container">
        <Transition name="fade">
          <router-view style="" />
        </Transition>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
    <AppFooter></AppFooter>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import AppNavigation from "./components/AppNavigation.vue";
import AppFooter from "./components/AppFooter.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    AppNavigation,
    AppFooter,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of `vue-loader` are you using? For Vue 3 you need v.15+

Comment: I had the exact same issue and got stuck figuring out how to fix it. Used the opportunity to migrate from vue-cli to Vite and that worked for me. Not really a fix, but maybe something to consider?

Comment: same here. After update from Vue 2 to Vue 3 :(

Comment: @paddyfields I have 17.4.2

Comment: I would also recommend everybody to just migrate to vite. I had exactly the same issue with @vue/complier-sfc and the same error message, but couldn't resolve it while using the vue-cli.

Comment: I opened a Github issue for this problem: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/10044